# storing images into sd card after loading it in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I am downloading images from server into the `ListView` , now to perform this task i am using [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java) example code. so far its working fine.

But i want to `save` images of `ListView` in a `SD card` but i am confused when to store the images as images are being downloaded Asynchronously and because of ViewHolder pattern its little tough for me to judge.

Once i stored it in a SD card next time i want to read it from memory only.

ImageDownload is storing bitmap in cache and fetching it from there once it gets downloaded.But the problem is its behavior is not predictable.

Sometimes it downloads from server and sometimes from cache.

so can anyone help me in finding what is the proper place to store the images in sd card once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your ImageDownloader class to save the image like this :

- add a parameter to download method like :

> ```
>  download(String url, ImageView imageView, Boolean saveData)
> ```

- make a global variable saveData in yout ID class :

> private Boolean saveData;

and store in it the value given as parameter in download dmethod:

> this.saveData = saveData;

- and the BitmapDownloaderTask's  onPostExecute method should look like this :

> @Override
>           protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
>               if (isCancelled()) {
>                   bitmap = null;
>               }
>
> ```
>         addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);
>
>         if (saveData == true) {
>             try {
>                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
>                 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (imageViewReference != null) {
>             ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
>             BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
>             // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
>             if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
>                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

where path is the path were you want to save the image .

and next time before you want to load the image you have to see if it is already downloaded and load it from the path otherwise call ImageDownloader.

that's it! enjoy!

Comment: Well i want to check when all the images are being downloaded. because  'download(String url, ImageView imageView, Boolean saveData)` function will be executed whenever the list items are loaded in getView()